# Executing and dynamically viewing result of a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a simple web app. In one particular page, I have to dynamically generate a list and have a calendar after every item in the list.

Here is the code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < goalsObj.length; i++) {
    var node = document.createElement("li");
    node.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
    node.setAttribute('id', 'g' + i);
    node.addEventListener('click', function () {
        viewGoal()
    }, false);
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(goalsObj[i]);
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    var cal = "<script>calendar()</script>";
    var calen = document.createTextNode(cal);
    document.getElementById("sortable").appendChild(node);
    document.getElementById("sortable").appendChild(calen);
}
```

but the problem is that instead of the output of the `calendar()` function being computed and shown, I am getting just `"script calendar() /script"` everywhere. What's wrong? What should I do?

Comment: ... I honestly dont understand why you cant see the answer to this, or maybe you dont understand what `createTEXTnode` means....

Comment: You should use escaping characters for <,> signs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
var calen = document.createElement("div");
document.getElementById("calen").innerHTML=calendar();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
scriptElement.type = 'text/javascript';
scriptElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode('calendar();'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a script element for this. If I understand you correctly, then you simply want to display the result of `calendar()`. So you can just call the function and pass the result to the `createTextNode` function:

```
var calen = document.createTextNode(calendar());
```

What you are doing right now is creating a string `"<script>calendar()</script>"` and then creating a textnode with this string as content. Nothing gets executed, because `createTextNode` just does that, it creates a TEXTnode.

Comment: It's not working. I am getting 'undefined' as the output. What else can be the right thing to do?

Comment: @coder in this case you calender function probably returns `undefined`. So there must be another error inside this function. Here is a fiddle that demonstrates, that it works in principle: http://jsfiddle.net/w9mm7/

Comment: These are the end few lines: calendar_html += '</tr>';
  calendar_html += '</table>';  return calendar_html;   of the calendar function. What should I do?